# Any solutions to the functional equation?

Tags: functions

while randomly thinking about functions, i tried to find general solutions to the equation:

$f(g(x)) = f(x)g(x)$

i managed to find one particular solution without any mathematical proof

for $ a  \in \mathbb{R}$:  $\hspace{2cm}$ $f(x)= x + a $ $\hspace{2cm}$ $g(x)= \frac{a}{x+a-1}$

Are there other solutions to this equation and can the solution that I found be obtained mathematically?

Comment: A not very exciting solution: $g(x) = 0$ and $f(x)$ is any function with $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Another: $g(x) = x+1, f(x) = \Gamma(x+1)\;f(0)$

Comment: Another: $f(x) =x+1, g(x) =1/x$.

Comment: Another : $f(x)=g(x)=x^2$